# Is the addition of "might be" necessary in this sentence?

Tags: verbs

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

*"Whatever the magician's opinion, most of the committee members agreed that war was not an option."*

Or:

*"Whatever the magician's opinion **might be**, most of the committee members agreed that war was not an option."*

--

Is the addition of "might be" necessary? The shorter version without a verb in the first part feels more natural to me, but perhaps it's not grammatical?

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical and clear. The longer version simply adds more words to say the same thing.

Comment: They both are fine but one is more formal than the other.